# Writing an unmanaged c++ code that depend on managed code

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, wrapper

I am trying to write a basic wrapper for assimp library in c++ to use it in C# code, also this c++ wrapper depends on a C# library I have written it in the past, and I do not have much knowledge in wrappers, so could you please help me.

here is the header file:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;


namespace Assimp {

#ifndef MESH_H
#define MESH_H
public ref class Mesh
{
public:
    List<Graphics::OpenGL::Vertex>^ vertices;
    List<UInt32>^ indices;
    List<Graphics::OpenGL::Texture>^ textures;
    Graphics::OpenGL::VertexArray<float> VAO;

    Mesh(List<Graphics::OpenGL::Vertex>^ Vertices, List<UInt32>^ Indices, List<Graphics::OpenGL::Texture>^ Textures);
    void Draw(Graphics::OpenGL::Shader^ Shader);

private:
    void setupMesh();
};
#endif
}
```

the namespace `Graphics::OpenGL` is a C# library I have written in the past, and these classes live in it: `Vertex, Textrue, Shader and VertexArray<T>` and they have basic implementation for OpenGL objects, also I have to mention that I have added a reference to the `Graphics` library in c++ project, but I still have many errors that I do not know why, here is them:

```
Error   C2653   'Graphics': is not a class or namespace name
Error   C2065   'Vertex': undeclared identifier
Error   C2065   'Texture': undeclared identifier
Error   C2182   'Draw': illegal use of type 'void'
Error   C2955   'System::Collections::Generic::List': use of class generic requires generic argument list   Assimp
Error   C2923   'System::Collections::Generic::List': 'Vertex' is not a valid generic type argument for parameter 'T'
Error   C2923   'System::Collections::Generic::List': 'Texture' is not a valid generic type argument for parameter 'T'
Error   C2065   'Shader': undeclared identifier
Error (active)  E2227   "Graphics::OpenGL::Vertex" is not a valid generic argument
Error (active)  E2227   "Graphics::OpenGL::Texture" is not a valid generic argument
```

also I have referenced the managed 'Assimp' library from C# code and it says: `Error    CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Assimp' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)` although I have added a reference to it.

Comment: I see no `#include` for the C++ header where your  `Graphics::` stuff is declared ...  meaning your C++ code does not recognize its classes structures and functions ... even if they are linked

Comment: I have thought that, there is no need to do so. But yes you are right, now it is working, THANKS A LOT!!